# Как сделать все сети Частными с помощью инструментария WMI?

Tags: windows, powershell, wmi

Чтобы сделать все сети частными в Windows 10, в PowerShell нужно выполнить команду:

```
Set-NetConnectionProfile -NetworkCategory Private
```

Как сделать то же самое с помощью инструментария WMI?

Comment: [Changing Windows Network Profile from "DomainAuthenticated" to Public](https://serverfault.com/questions/814557/)

Answer (score 0):

Хотелось бы, кончено, задачу целиком послушать, если, например, стоит вопрос по смене на удаленном хосте, то возможно проще пользоваться WinRM, если же задача именно WMI использовать, то можно, например, так:

```
get-ciminstance -Namespace root/StandardCimv2 -ClassName MSFT_NetConnectionProfile | set-ciminstance -property @{NetworkCategory="1"}
```